# Reg exp match until first occurence of a slash

Tags: regex

Input :IndicesQA-agg-calculation-ci/USAggModule:USAggTestCalcEngine

Output should be : IndicesQA-agg-calculation-ci

I have tried IndicesQA-.*[^/] , but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `IndicesQA-[^/]*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`([^\/]*)\/`](https://regex101.com/r/EmwX9o/2).

`$1` will give you what you want.